# check directory in REQUEST_URI against database records

Tags: php, mysql

im looking to validate directorys in the REQUEST_URI with entries in a database. i currently have a url structure that looks like the following

https://domain.com/accounts/customers/details

my database looks like this

IDNO - URL - PARENT

1 - accounts - 0

2 - customers - 1

3 - details - 2

!! i wasn't sure how to create a table for my question

what possible methods are there to check these individual parts of the url exist but are the parent or child of each other

so to clarify i want to check "accounts" exists in the database if it exists we see if "customers" exists in the database but its parent is 1 the same as the accounts id as in the table above

if this doesnt exist i will return a 404

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would probably set up a translation table that stores foreign keys for each of your other tables. Here is an example, say you have these three tables:

Accounts:

```
Account ID  |     Name    |  Other Info
     1      |  Account 1  |   Whatever
     2      |  Account 2  |     Meh
     3      |  Account 3  |     Woo!
```

Customers:

```
Customer ID |     Name    |  Birthday
     1      |     Matt    |   Jan 1
     2      |    Nathan   |   Jan 2
```

Details:

```
Details ID  |     Name    |  Other Stuff
     1      |  Details 1  |   DETAILS
     2      |  Details 2  |    MORE
```

These three tables house the data for your three models. Essentially you add a fourth table that links them together:

Translation Table:

```
Account  |  Customer  |  Details
   1     |     1      |     1
   1     |     2      |     1
   2     |     2      |     2
   3     |     1      |     2
```

You are pointing to the UIDs of the other tables in this table. What this allows you to do is logically associate the three groups together. The table above is basically saying this:

- Account 1 contains Matt and his details are DETAILS
- Account 1 contains Nathan and his details are DETAILS
- Account 2 contains Nathan and his details are MORE
- Account 3 contains Matt and his details are MORE

This allows you to do things like getting all of your queries against the translation table and just JOIN the data when you need it. If your PHP you would simply check your arguments agains the database:

```
https://domain.com/1/2/2
```

With that route you would have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM translation_table
    WHERE `Account` = 1
    AND `Customer` = 2
    AND `Details` = 2
```

If it returns a row, then you are golden and you can just join the data where you need it and render the page. If it doesn't exist, return a 404 header.

Comment: is there anyway else to do this with the one table as i have an existing table that we are moving to seo friendly urls there are multiple urls for example www.domain.com/mobile-phones which is a page then another page like www.domain.com/iphones i just want to tidy up the url so it will look www.domain.com/mobile-phone/iphones and if the user removed iphone from the url it will go back to the www.domain.com/mobile-phones page